# How to call back to the fragmentactivity from an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried to use the intent to go to another activity from a fragment. And when I want to call back to the previous `FragmentActivity` from this activity, the app crashes due to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`. I think that is because I applied `transaction.commit()` to the `FragmentActivity` which caused the crash. But if I remove `transcation.commit()`, it seems that the fragment won't be on the screen. Any good solutions?

```
public void onReturn(APIReturn result) {
    switch (result.state) {
        case ServerError:
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case Success:
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Success.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(EditProfile.this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

The `MainActivity` is the `FragmentActivity`that I want to call back from `EditProfile`. In the `MainActivity`, there is a `showFragment()` method which has the `commit();` in the end.

```
public void showFragment(int position) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    hideFragments(transaction);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            if (fg1 == null) {
                fg1 = new SpelersFragment();
                transaction.add(R.id.fl_content, fg1);
            } else {
                transaction.show(fg1);
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (fg2 == null) {

                fg2 = new WedstrijdenFragment();
                transaction.add(R.id.fl_content, fg2);
            } else {

                transaction.show(fg2);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (fg3 == null) {

                fg3 = new ProfileFragment();
                transaction.add(R.id.fl_content, fg3);
            } else {

                transaction.show(fg3);
            }
            break;
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the result back to MainActivity? Is the flow something similar to this: MainActivity -- > EditProfileActivity -- > MainActivity ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. In one of the fragments of the MainActivity, I called the intent to the EditProfileActivity. When the editing is finished, I want go back to the MainActivity and show the default fragment.

Comment: Have you tried commitAllowingStateLoss() ?